# How to reorder the rows and columns of a correlation matrix created within a function

Tags: r, function, matrix, functional-programming, correlation

Consider the following data frame `dat1`:

```r
set.seed(123)
dat1 <- data.frame(Loc = rep(letters[1:20], each = 10),
                   ID = 1:200,
                   var1 = rnorm(200),
                   var3 = rnorm(200),
                   var4 = rnorm(200),
                   var5 = rnorm(200),
                   var6 = rnorm(200))
dat1$ID <- factor(dat1$ID)
```

The following function will use the `rstatix` package to do a `dunn_test` between the levels of `Loc` for whichever `var` is specified, and it will return a correlation matrix of the p values from the `dunn_test`:

```r
library(rstatix)
dunn.cor <- function(dat, var, gv){
  res <- dat%>% rstatix::dunn_test(as.formula(paste(var, "~", gv)))
  p <- res$p
 dst <- matrix(NA, 20, 20)
 dst[lower.tri(dst)] <- p
 dst <- as.dist(dst)
 attr(dst, "Labels") <- levels(dat1$Loc)
 dst <- as.matrix(dst, upper=TRUE, lower=TRUE)
 diag(dst) <- 1
 dst <- round(dst,2)
 return(dst)
}
#example for var1:
dunn.cor(dat=dat1, var= "var1", gv = "Loc")
```

I would like to create an object `order` outside of the function that specifies the order that I want the rows AND columns to appear in the matrix.
for example:

```r
order <- c("m", "l", "n", "h", "p", "j", "r", "k", "c", "d", "f", "o", "t", "i", "g", "s", "e", "q", "b", "a")
```

To clarify, I want the rows AND the columns of the matrix to be in this order, just like a regular correlation matrix. How can I modify the function so that the matrix rows and columns will be in this order?

Comment: @akrun sorry I forgot to include that, please see the update

Comment: if you want to assign the `dimnames` then `dimnaes(out) <- list(order, order)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we need to have this in a specific order, may be create a `factor` with `levels` specified

```
dat1$Loc <- factor(dat1$Loc, levels = order)
```

and then we apply

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(tibble)
out <- dat1 %>% 
   rstatix::dunn_test(var1 ~ Loc) %>%
   select(group1, group2, p) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = group2, values_from = p, values_fill = list(p = 0)) %>% 
   column_to_rownames('group1') %>% 
   as.matrix
out1 <- out + t(out)



dimnames(out1)
#[[1]]
# [1] "m" "l" "n" "h" "p" "j" "r" "k" "c" "d" "f" "o" "t" "i" "g" "s" "e" "q" "b"

#[[2]]
# [1] "l" "n" "h" "p" "j" "r" "k" "c" "d" "f" "o" "t" "i" "g" "s" "e" "q" "b" "a"
```

If we need a binary matrix

```
out2 <- +(out1 <= 0.05)
```

and plot with `corrplot`

```
corrplot(out2, is.corr = FALSE, type = 'lower')
```

Comment: thanks, I like your solution. however it has proposed a new problem with what I am trying to do. maybe I should have included this in the question, but my actual goal with building this function to produce correlation plots with the `corrplot` package that show where significant differences are, my next step  (using objects in my function) was going to be: `for (i in 1:nrow(dst)) {
    for (j in 1:ncol(dst)) if (dst[i,j]<=0.05) dst[i,j]=1 else dst[i,j]=0
}` which makes binary output for sigs (1) vs non-sigs (0) and then `corrplot(dst, is.corr = F, type = "lower")` to plot.

Comment: Im not sure how to adapt what you did to make this happen, how can I use the tidyverse syntax and get a full top triangle and bottom triangle (like a plain correlation matrix) like my function produces? Or at least in this example how do I include a row for `Loc == a` and a column for `Loc == b` to complete the upper triangle, and treat the NAs in a way that the `corrplot` would exclude them?

Comment: @Ryan once you have the `out`, I guess you can do `out + t(out)` if we use `pivot_wider`, values_fill = list(p = 0))`

Comment: @Ryan. Regarding your `for` loop, is it needed `+(out1 <= 0.05)`

Comment: I do apologize, I am a bit confused about what you mean. would It be easier to explain if I post a new question specifically about making the plot using your code? I will accept this one

Comment: @Ryan If i do, `corrplot(out2, is.corr = FALSE, type = 'lower')` i get a plot

Comment: @Ryan I was looking at your code with `for(i in 1:nrow(dst)`.  My understanding is that you are looping over the rows/columns to convert it to binary matrix when this can be done without looping as the operation is vectorized

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216907/discussion-between-ryan-and-akrun).